# Echo based on number of instances in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach, count

I have the following foreach loop:

```
<?php if(!empty($strategy->assisting)):?>
     <ul class="needs-padding">
      <?php foreach($strategy->assisting as $asst): ?>
          <li><?= $asst->full_name; ?></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Rather than just spitting out all the $asst inside of li's, I need to echo 'multiple' if there is more than one (with the list after appearing after so show I can hide/show it with js) or echo out just the $asst if there is only one instance.

I tried this but its obviously wrong as it just prints out 'multiple' for every instance of $asst.

```
                  <?php if(!empty($strategy->assisting)):?>
                        <ul class="needs-padding assisting-members">
                            <?php $count = 0; ?>
                            <?php foreach($strategy->assisting as $asst): ?>
                                <?php $count ++; ?>
                                <?php if($count > 1){
                                    echo '<a href="#">Multiple</a>';
                                    // echo '<li>' . $asst->full_name . '</li>';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<li>' . $asst->full_name . '</li>';
                                } ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why not just `if (count($strategy->assisting) >  1)` do the foreach loop? else echo `$strategy->assisting[0]->full_name` into the list.

Comment: have you tired putting the `if($count > 1){` outside of the foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as shown below:

```
<?php if(!empty($strategy->assisting)):?>
     <?php $count = count($strategy->assisting); ?>
     <ul class="needs-padding">
      <?php foreach($strategy->assisting as $k => $asst): ?>
          <?php if ($count > 1 && $k == 0) echo '<a href="#">Multiple</a>'; ?>
          <li <?php if ($count > 1) echo "style='display:none;'"; ?>><?= $asst->full_name; ?></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `$strategy->assisting` is an array, you should be able to use `count($strategy->assisting)` instead of a `$count` variable. Something like: (edited to only print "Multiple" once)

```
              <?php if(!empty($strategy->assisting)):?>
                    <ul class="needs-padding assisting-members">
                        <?php printedMultiple = false; ?>
                        <?php foreach($strategy->assisting as $asst): ?>
                            <?php if(count($strategy->assisting) > 1 and !printedMultiple){
                                echo '<a href="#">Multiple</a>';
                                printedMultiple = true;
                                // echo '<li>' . $asst->full_name . '</li>';
                            } elseif (!printedMultiple) {
                                echo '<li>' . $asst->full_name . '</li>';
                            } ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
```